# adding additional arugments to brent_find_minima

Tags: c++, boost

I am very new to C++ so please forgive my ignorance. I am looking at using the Boost library to carry out a 1D optimisation. I am using the `brent_find_minima` function, and have looked at the documentation page [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/internals1/minima.html). But for the input into the `brent_find_minima` function there is another function `f` that needs to be given.

An example using it is shown [here](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/Boost/Math/Tools/brent_find_minima) but their function only takes in one argument. i.e. `double f(double x){...}`, If you wanted to provide additional arguments to `f` so that the optimisation parameters changes e.g. `double f(double x, int y, int z){...}` where `y` and `z` can change the results of function `f` for the same `x` is this possible to specify this at the brent_find_minima stage?

Given I am very new to C++ any examples showing how this is done/altering the examples given in the link to accept more than 1 argument would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass fixed values for y,z you can just just use a bind expression:

```
double f(double x, int y, int z) 
{ return (y*sin(x) + z + x * cos(x)); }

brent_find_minima(std::bind(f, _1, 3, 4), 3.0, 4.0, 20);
```

That passes `3, 4` for `y, z`.

If that's not the case, I'm not convinced that Brent's algorithm is necessarily still a valid approach.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78c8b7b686edd3d2)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <functional> // functional
using namespace std::placeholders;

#include <boost/math/tools/minima.hpp>

double f(double x, int y, int z) 
{ return (y*sin(x) + z + x * cos(x)); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Result;
    // find a root of the function f in the interval x=[3.0, 4.0] with 20-bit precision
    Result r2 = boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima(std::bind(f, _1, 3, 4), 3.0, 4.0, 20);
    std::cout << "x=" << r2.first << " f=" << r2.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// output:
// x=3.93516 f=-0.898333
```

Comment: Here's the same with a manual function object: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cba30664291e366e

Answer (score 2):

It is always possible to provide a functor instead of a function.
In this case, the function specified takes one argument called from the brent_find_minimize function. If you want to include more parameters you need to write a functor like this:

```
struct f
{
    f(int y, int z) : _y(y), _z(z) { }
    // you may need a copy constructor and operator= here too ...

    double operator()(double x) 
    {  
        return _y*sin(x) + _z + x * cos(x);
    }
    int _y, _z;
};
```

Then you can pass it like this:

```
 Result r2 = boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima( f(10, 20), 3.0, 4.0, 20);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please give a full example of how that would work if your f was `double f(double x, int y, int z) { return (y*sin(x) + z + x * cos(x)); }`...sorry...I'm a bit new to functors/constructors/operators etc. and how it might differ from the `std::bind` approach?

Comment: @h.l.m I've added one in the comment to my answer

Comment: I edited the code. The difference with using std::bind is that a functor can also be used with non C++11 compliant compilers. For more information on std::bind, please check the reference here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind